# Export to PDF increase number of items per page

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, export-to-pdf

I have a grid control which I wish to export the content of. Upon initialisation, the `pageSize` attribute is set to 10 items however I want to increase the number of items per page during `exportToPDF`.

I have tried to modify the `pageSize` of the `dataSource` prior to carrying out the export but this seems to have no effect on the end product.

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");                                    
var filter = grid.dataSource.filter;
grid.dataSource.query({
    filter: filter,
    pageSize: 20, // has no effect on the exported PDF
    page: 1,
    group: [{
        field: "groupField1",
        dir: "asc"
    }, {
        field: "groupField2",
        dir: "asc"
    }, {
        field: "groupField3",
        dir: "asc"
    }]
});

var progress = $.Deferred();
grid._drawPDF(progress)
    .then(function (root) {
        return kendo.drawing.exportPDF(root, { forcePageBreak: ".page-break", multiPage: true });
    })
    .done(function (dataURI) {
        // ... do some manual manipulation of dataURI
        kendo.saveAs({
            dataURI: manipualtedDataURI
        });
progress.resolve();
```

Is there something I am missing so I can display more items on each page of the PDF export?

**EDIT**

Including my grid definition with the `pdfExport` function suggested by the below answer (which never gets called):

```
var grid = $("#reportGrid").kendoGrid({                        
    pdf: {
        allPages: true,
        avoidLinks: true,
        repeatHeaders: true,            
        template: kendo.template($("#page-template").html()),
        scale: 0.7,
        margin: { top: "2.5cm", right: "1cm", bottom: "1.5cm", left: "1cm" },
        paperSize: "A4",
        landscape: true
    },
    // *this function is not getting called*
    pdfExport: function(e) {
        e.sender.dataSource.pageSize(10);
        e.promise.done(function() {
            e.sender.dataSource.pageSize(20);
        });
    },
    toolbar: kendo.template($("#template").html()),
    ...
});
```

Note: A template is used to include a header / footer on each page of the PDF export.

Another note: 'Manual manipulation of dataURI' includes going out to the server to perform a merge with another PDF file, so I cannot use the default export via the grid :(

**EDIT 2**

I have extended the [Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/UzOXO/7) example from @R.K.Saini's answer to use the method by which I need to generate the PDF export (as per original post). 
The snippet logs the URI of the grid being exported and when the `pdfExport` function is called.  As you will see, when using the built in grid 'Export to PDF' button, the `pdfExport` function is triggered but when using the additional button below the grid, it is not.

Answer (score 2):

You can use pdfExport event to change page size of your grid datasource before pdf export started and then when the export finish you just need to revert back the previous page size.

The call back function of this event receive grid instance as e.sender and and a promise as e.promise which can be used to set back the page size when exporting finish.

For more info check http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-pdfExport

```
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    pdf: {
        allPages: true
    },
    pdfExport: function(e) {
      e.sender.dataSource.pageSize(10);
      e.promise.done(function() {
          e.sender.dataSource.pageSize(20);
      });
    },
    ...
   //Other configguration
 });
```

Here is a working demo http://dojo.telerik.com/UzOXO

**Edit**

You can also change grid page size in your custom export function just change grid page size before calling _drawPdf() function and change it back when done.

```
$("#btnPdfExport").kendoButton({
  click: function () {
      var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");                                    

      var progress = $.Deferred();
      // Change grid datasource pagesize before calling _drawPDF
      grid.dataSource.pageSize(20);
      grid._drawPDF(progress)
          .then(function (root) {
              return kendo.drawing.exportPDF(root, { forcePageBreak: ".page-break", multiPage: true });
          })
          .done(function (dataURI) {
              console.log("Exporting "  + dataURI);
              kendo.saveAs({
                  dataURI: dataURI,
                  fileName: "export.pdf"
              });
              progress.resolve();
              // Change grid datasource pagesize when done
              grid.dataSource.pageSize(10);
          });            
  }
});
```

Check Update DOJO here http://dojo.telerik.com/UzOXO/8

Comment: Your example works but when combined with my code (which triggers the export to PDF manually using `exportPDF`), the `pdfExport` function never gets called.

Comment: Don't you call saveAsPDF() function on grid ? It will trigger pdfExport event
See documentation  http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-saveAsPDF

Comment: No, as per original question (with updated answer to include further details) I use a combination of `exportPDF` to get the URI of the grid export, go to server to perform "merge" with another PDF which returns the complete URI and finally use `kendo.saveAs(finalURI)`

Comment: Can you add a sample snippet

Comment: I have extended your dojo example in the question (I think this is what you are asking for)

Comment: Ok, you are calling _drawPDF() function on grid. You change pageSize for grid before calling _drawPDF()

Comment: Already doing that through the `dataSource.query()`, which does change the size of the grid `pageSize` but has no effect on the export.

Comment: Your example works fine until combined with `paperSize`, `landscape`, `margin`, `scale` PDF attributes (as per original question grid definition which are not in your example), so at least it's been narrowed down to this seeming to be the cause of the issue.